# May I get Null pointer exception from this routine?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have written a below routine in Java, I need to know that the code is Null Pointer Safe or not:

```
public class TRM_Fields {
    public static String returnActualValue(String Staffing_Event,
            String CurrentValue, String PriorValue) {
        String returnValue;
        returnValue = null;

        if ("TRM".equalsIgnoreCase(Staffing_Event) && CurrentValue == null
                && PriorValue != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(PriorValue)) {
            returnValue = PriorValue;
        } else {
            returnValue = CurrentValue;
        }
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Any of the parameter Staffing_Event, CurrentValue and  PriorValue may be null.

If it is not Null Pointer Safe what should I do to achieve that?

Comment: It seems to be safe, `"".equalsIgnoreCase(null)` do not throw a `NullPointerException`

Comment: Why are you _still_ not simply referring to the documentation? I told you off for this over a year ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is safe. You are correctly using `"constantString".equals(someObject)` to ensure a null-safe comparison.

Some other comments:

- Your method is hard to read because you are using `TitleCase` for Java variables, when they should be `camelCase`.
- You only have two possible return values. So you can simplify your method as follows:

  ```
  public static String returnActualValue(String staffingEvent,
          String currentValue, String priorValue) {

      if ("TRM".equalsIgnoreCase(staffingEvent) && currentValue == null
              && priorValue != null && !"".equalsIgnoreCase(priorValue)) {
          return priorValue;
      } else {
          return currentValue;
      }
  }
  ```

  Note that the `else` construct isn't necessary, so it's a matter of style whether you include that structure or simply have `return currentValue;`.

Comment: Ok I will take care of camelCase.

Comment: I am writing this code in Talend.So I need to return outside of the if and else otherwise it gives error.

Comment: @AbdulManaf Interesting. I'm not familiar with Talend - what error do you get, out of interest? It seems odd that semantically identical code should be rejected.

Comment: This method must return a result of type String

Comment: @AbdulManaf Maybe you typed it wrong somehow? My code above compiles just fine with a standard Java compiler.

Comment: If the method itself returns the null then it will not throw the exception ?

Comment: @AbdulManaf This method may return null. Whether that causes an exception somewhere depends upon the rest of your code or how this Talend product behaves.